# Set Values in Numpy Array Based Upon Another Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

#### 1 `term_map` tracks which term is in which position.

```
In [256]: term_map = np.array([2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0])

In [257]: term_map
Out[257]: array([2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0])
```

#### 2 `term_scores` tracks the weight of each term at each position.

```
In [258]: term_scores = np.array([5, 6, 9, 8, 9, 4, 5, 1, 2, 1])

In [259]: term_scores
Out[259]: array([5, 6, 9, 8, 9, 4, 5, 1, 2, 1])
```

#### 3 Get the unique values and the inverse indices.

```
In [260]: unqID, idx = np.unique(term_map, return_inverse=True)

In [261]: unqID
Out[261]: array([0, 2, 3, 4])
```

#### 4 Compute the scores for the unique values.

```
In [262]: value_sums = np.bincount(idx, term_scores)

In [263]: value_sums
Out[263]: array([  4.,  16.,   9.,  21.])
```

#### 5 Initialize Array To Update. The indices correspond to the values in the `term_map` variable.

```
In [254]: vocab = np.zeros(13)

In [255]: vocab
Out[255]: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

#### 6 DESIRED: Insert the values 4 corresponding to the positions listed in 3 into the `vocab` variable.

```
In [255]: updated_vocab
Out[255]: array([ 4.,  0.,  16.,  9.,  21.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

How do I create 6?

Comment: So, the question is?

Comment: @Divakar He's unable to do stage 6 I guess.

Comment: yeah @TonyTannous that's correct. Sorry for not making it more clear.

Comment: I would think that's trivial given the 5 more difficult hurdles covered before that.

Comment: I'd like to not use a for loop if possible. This is pretty close - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373079/numpy-function-to-set-elements-of-array-to-a-value-given-a-list-of-indices

Comment: `vocab[unqID] = value_sums`?

Comment: OMG...it was that simple...feeling a little sheepish...thank you @Divakar

Comment: @Divakar you've answered 30~ seconds before I did. put ur answer I'll delete mine.

Comment: @TonyTannous I think it's fine really. Keep yours :)

Comment: @Divakar :) I was busy deleting all the prints from my code as I was checking the values :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, we can avoid the `np.unique` step to directly get to the desired output by feeding in `term_map` and `term_scores` to `np.bincount` and also mention the length of the output array with its optional argument `minlength`.

Thus, we could simply do -

```
final_output = np.bincount(term_map, term_scores, minlength=13)
```

Sample run -

```
In [142]: term_map = np.array([2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0])
     ...: term_scores = np.array([5, 6, 9, 8, 9, 4, 5, 1, 2, 1])
     ...: 

In [143]: np.bincount(term_map, term_scores, minlength=13)
Out[143]: 
array([  4.,   0.,  16.,   9.,  21.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
         0.,   0.])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np

term_map = np.array([2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0])
term_scores = np.array([5, 6, 9, 8, 9, 4, 5, 1, 2, 1])
unqID, idx = np.unique(term_map, return_inverse=True)
value_sums = np.bincount(idx, term_scores)

vocab = np.zeros(13)
vocab[unqID] = value_sums
print(vocab)
```

**OUT:** `[  4.   0.  16.   9.  21.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]`